# how to make image from some some other images in java

Tags: java, image

i wanna make an image from other images in java, i have some tiles and i've cropped the parts i need and i wanna group them in another image; here an exemple :

[image]

lets say that i have cropped each square in an image, i need a function to group them in 1 image again like the first picture

```
public Image groupe(Image[][] images){
       Image image=new Image();
       for(int i=0;i<images.length;i++){
           for(int j=0;j<images[0].length;j++){
               //here i need a function to groupe the images into image
           }
       }
       return image;
}
```

Comment: Basically you create a new [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getGraphics%28%29) and then draw other images into the buffer with [drawImage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29)

Comment: i forget to say that i'm using Slick Image librarie so it looks hard to convert from Image to BufferedImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Crop {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //split
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\workspaceIndigo2\\crop\\src\\plasma.gif"));

    System.out.println("Original Image Dimension: "+image.getWidth()+"x"+image.getHeight());

    //Get the cropped image
    BufferedImage firstHalf = image.getSubimage(0, 0, (image.getWidth()/2),image.getHeight());
    BufferedImage secondHalf = image.getSubimage(image.getWidth()/2, 0, image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight());

    //Create a file to stream the out buffered image to
    File croppedFile1 = new File("E:\\workspaceIndigo2\\crop\\src\\half1.png");
    File croppedFile2 = new File("E:\\workspaceIndigo2\\crop\\src\\half2.png");

    //Write the cropped file
    ImageIO.write(firstHalf, "png", croppedFile1);
    ImageIO.write(secondHalf, "png", croppedFile2);

    //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    //join
    BufferedImage joined = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(), image.getType());
    BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\workspaceIndigo2\\crop\\src\\half1.png"));
    BufferedImage image2 = ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\workspaceIndigo2\\crop\\src\\half2.png"));

    Graphics2D graph = joined.createGraphics();
    graph.drawImage(image1, 0, 0,null);
    graph.drawImage(image2, image1.getWidth(), 0,null);

    File joinedFile = new File("E:\\workspaceIndigo2\\crop\\src\\joined.png");
    ImageIO.write(joined, "png", joinedFile);
}

}
```